# The probability of $7 7$’s in $17$ digit random number?

Tags: probability

$$205-7895777-7786742$$

What is the probability that the number $7$ appears $7$ times in a $17$ digit random number?

Comment: Hint: Frame the question as success (and failures) and independent trials

Comment: Exactly 7 times or at least 7 times?  17 digit random number may have $0$ as a leading digit.  Are these excluded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us decide MSD (left most) first,then assign the remaining 7's, finally fill the rest digits.

1. MSD $\neq$ 7,  8 choices for this digit; $C_7^{16}$ choices for all seven 7's to take 7 digits;  $9^9$ choices for the rest 9 digits. Total  8$C_7^{16}9^9$ choices for this case.
2. MSD =7, only one choice for this digit; $C_6^{16}$ choices for the other six 7's to take 6 digits; $10^9$ choices for the rest 10 digits. Total  $C_6^{16}$ $10^9$  choices for this case.

Adding results from 1 and 2 , there are  8$C_7^{16}9^9$+ $C_6^{16}$ $10^9$  choices for  seven 7's in a 17 digits number. With 9.10$^{16}$  possible 17 digits numbers, the asked probability is $\frac{8C_7^{16}9^9+ C_6^{16}10^9 }{9.10^{16}}$.